# Why does cmd.exe have different errorlevel behavior on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

If I make a batch script named temp.bat (for example) containing:

```
exit /b 1
```

When I run it in various ways, I get different behavior on my 32-bit XP system vs. a 64-bit XP system.

On 32-bit:

```
> temp.bat
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
> cmd /c temp.bat
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

On 64-bit:

```
> temp.bat
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
> cmd /c temp.bat
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
```

I've searched through the cmd.exe options and I have been unable to find any options controlling how it propagates errorlevel information from batch scripts.  At this point I'm unable to find any rational explanation for this difference.

Comment: My guess: The 32-bit version maintaining the original behaviour is due to backwards compatibility. The 64-bit version doesn't have that requirement, so has behaviour more friendly to automated scripts.

Comment: Aha! Raymond's daughter [http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/24/45779.aspx] vs Raymond's bridesmaid [http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/12/02/9931184.aspx#9931572]

Comment: Can't reproduce here. Works the same on both 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Anon: batch files have no way of indicating whether they want to run 32-bit or 64-bit on a 64-bit system. Your point there is essentially false. What doesn't work anymore on 64-bit systems is 16-bit executables; 32-bit continues to work just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to be careful with exit /b since it does not actually work correctly in all instances. For example:

`temp.bat&&echo 0||echo 1`

If temp.bat contains exit /b 1 you would expect 1 to be printed, but it is not. Sadly, the only way to really set a working exit code for a batch file is to use `@%COMSPEC% /C exit 1` as the **last** line in the batch file

Comment: Excellent, I tried your suggestion and it works the same on both machines.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with Anders's example is that it uses a .bat file. If you use a .cmd file, exit works as documented.

The main point of having both .bat and .cmd files seems to be backward compatibility: if it's executing a .bat file, cmd tries to emulate the pre-NT CLI, command.com, which had much simpler error handling.

At least that's my surmise. I stumbled on this thread while googling for official docs on the .bat/.cmd thing, which I can't seem to find.

Comment: At least on Windows 10, .bat/.cmd makes no difference for this. Anders's command prints `0` in both cases.

Comment: Which only makes the whole .bat/.cmd thing even more mysterious and frustrating. No matter: cmd.exe should be considered legacy support. If you find its behavior confusing, it's time for you to switch to PowerShell.