# Return error message from batch file

Tags: windows, vba, batch-file

I'm shelling to a batch file from VBA, to launch an exec file, such as Notepad.exe.  I would like to return an indication or message back to VBA if the exec file wasn't found.  So far, I've been doing this by having the bat write a message to a text file, then have VBA examine this file.  This approach seems a bit kludgy, but so far I haven't come across an alternate method.

```
@echo off

set EM="C:\Msg.txt"
if exist %EM% del %EM%

set FL=%SystemRoot%\system32\xnotepad.exe

if not exist %FL% (
echo %FL% not found > %EM%
goto done
)

Start "" %FL%

:done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in VBA,

```
Dim oSHELL, batchname, usr, pass, exitcode
Set oSHELL = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
usr="username"
pass="password"
batchname="batchFile.bat"

' Arguments ToRun, Style (0=hide), Waitforend
exitcode = oSHELL.Run(""""+batchname+""" """+usr+""" """+pass+"""", 0, True)
```

and in your batch

```
exit somenumber
```

should return `somenumber` to `exitcode`

---

Actual code I used:

```
Sub q27097252()
Dim oSHELL, batchname, usr, pass, exitcode
Set oSHELL = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
usr = ""
pass = ""
batchname = "c:\106x\q27097252.bat"

' Arguments ToRun, Style (0=hide), Waitforend
exitcode = oSHELL.Run("""" + batchname + """ """ + usr + """ """ + pass + """", 0, True)
MsgBox (exitcode)
End Sub
```

With batch `c:\106x\q27097252.bat`

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
EXIT %time:~-1%

GOTO :EOF
```

Ran perfectly well for me in VBA code editor/F5 (expected result: messagebox showing 0..9 at random)

---

Following comment/solution when using Windows XP:

It would appear the `exit /b number` option simply sets `errorlevel` whereas `exit number` actually sets the termination code.
Termination code is 0 under XP since `cmd.exe` actually terminated normally — whereas Windows 7 (and later) appears to assign the current `errorlevel` as exit code for the `cmd.exe` process.
Hence, use `exit number` by preference for compatibility with XP — code adjusted to suit.

Comment: Thanks, but no matter what I set `somenumber` to, `exitcode` always remains at 0.  I must be doing something wrong, will look at this some more tomorrow.

Comment: I'm using your VBA code verbetim (but without usr, pass params) with a test bat file that contains 1 line `exit /b 3`.  But no matter what I try, `exitcode` is always = 0, so the error code is not being returned.  Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, I'm using both your VBA and bat code exactly as you have it (copied & pasted), just changed the name of the bat file to match mine.  Still no dice, just returns 0.  Interestingly, if I change the bat file name to `cmd.exe`, then manually type `exit /b 3` from the command line, the exitcode works as expected. I'm running this on Win XP, if that makes any difference (shouldn't).  Thanks for you help and patience.

Comment: Well, I tried it on both of my Win XP systems, didn't work.  Borrowed a friend's Win 7 laptop, and presto - it worked!  So my problem must be a Win XP issue. Will let you know if it gets resolved, thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593357/exit-code-lost-from-child-process-in-windows-xp-not-in-windows-server-2003/17124533#17124533), seems we need to use `exit #` with WinXP, and not `exit /b #`.  Don't completely understand why, but it seems to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with the EXIT command. Take a look at EXIT /?