# %ERRORLEVEL% is not working incase multiple commands on a Single line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command, command-prompt

I am trying the below commands and want to get exit of my `process(%ERRORLEVEL%)`. But it is  returning `previous(last)` executed exit code result of `sample.exe`. I want to get exit code of current command. My requirement is to execute multiple commands in single line*(not batch script)*.

Command:

```
cmd /c sample.bat "test" > c:\ouput.log & echo %ERRORLEVEL% > c:\returnCode.log
```

I even tried using "setlocal enableDelayedExpansion" like below. Still It is not returning the exit code of current command

```
cmd /c setlocal enableDelayedExpansion & sample.bat "test" > c:\ouput.log & echo %ERRORLEVEL% > c:\returnCode.log
```

Please let me know the way to get current command's exit code.

Comment: EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL% is correct way to return exit code               **link for example** - http://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/returning-error-code-on-scripts-how-to.html

Comment: @Bot: This is true _in a Batch file_, but there is "*(not batch script)*" here!

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
cmd /V:ON /c sample.exe "test" > c:\ouput.log ^& echo !ERRORLEVEL! ^> c:\returnCode.log
```

/V:ON switch have the same effect of `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`. For further details, type: `cmd /?`

**EDIT**: Small error fixed, the `&` character must be escaped with `^`, otherwise, the `echo !ERRORLEVEL!` command is *not* executed in the cmd /V:ON !!!

**EDIT**: Escaping the echo redirection via `^>` causes just that echo to be piped into the log.  If you do not escape that, the entire command is piped there, i.e. including the stdout stream from "sample.exe".

Comment: Thank you for you response. The above command is printing "!ERRORLEVEL!"  instead exit code value in c:\returnCode.log. I even tried with %ERRORLEVEL%, still it is printing last executed command exit code.
/V:ON /c sample.exe "test" > c:\ouput.log & echo %ERRORLEVEL% > c:\returnCode.log

Comment: And perhaps it is possible that the second `>` needs also to be escaped: `^& echo !ERRORLEVEL! ^> ...` Or the first one, perhaps? You need to do some tests here...

Comment: I believe both `>` need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd /c sample.exe "test" > c:\ouput.log & call echo %%ERRORLEVEL%% > c:\returnCode.log
```

Should work for you. See endless SO items related to `delayedexpansion`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the above command , still it is printing last executed command exit code. 
cmd /c sample.bat "test" > c:\ouput.log & call echo %%ERRORLEVEL%% > c:\returnCode.log

Comment: I believe we're not getting the full story here. There appears to be no reason to run `sample.exe` under `cmd`. I'd suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097252/return-error-message-from-batch-file/27097793#27097793 . What seems to be happening is that `cmd` is terminating normally without setting an exit code via `exit` (may differ XP/W7+.) Perhaps you need to either run `sample.exe` without invoking `cmd` or to contrive to exit `cmd` after `exit %errorlevel%` (within the subsidiary `cmd` context)

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your response. I am able to get the exit code of current executed command with below command, only when I run through WMI class(Win32_Process). Using WMI client, I am executing the below command on Remote machine and it is working fine i.e. able to write exit code in Retrun.txt

Command:
cmd /V:ON /c sample.bat "test" > c:\Output.txt & echo !ERRORLEVEL! > c:\Return.txt

But if I run the same command in command prompt of the same remote machine, it is printing "!ERRORLVEL!" in Return.txt instead of "sample.bat" exit code.

I am curious to know why it is not working if I run from Command prompt of the same machine locally.

Comment: The explanation is in the answer. Specifying `/V:ON` on the CMD's command line enables delayed expansion. The already open CMD session that you are trying to run your command in apparently was not started with the `/V:ON` switch - meaning the delayed expansion was (and remains) not enabled. (As to *why* delayed expansion is needed – it's because of the `!` syntax, which *is* delayed expansion.)